# Get 2nd element from HTML tag Python/BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, format

I want to scrape elements from a page, for example the page-
https://www.aacr.org/?s=breast+cancer&search_type=global

The tag in html for the title, has an html link and the title attached. When I run my code, it prints both the HTML (first position) and then the title(second position/what i want)

For example- the print returns ->
<a href="https://www.aacr.org/patients-caregivers/cancer/breast-cancer/" **title="Breast Cancer**">Breast Cancer,

I just want whats in bold/the second element, any assistance?
Here is my code -

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

productlinks = []
sam=[]
for x in range(1,3):
    url=f'https://www.aacr.org/page/{x}/?s=breast+cancer&search_type=global'
    r=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
    productlist=soup.find_all('div',class_='blog-content')
    for item in productlist:
        title=soup.find_all('h3')
        print(title)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do one more iteration to get what you want, by iterating through each a tag (I kept your code intact and added the extra loop, so that you can see the nuts and bolts on how to do this in general, not just for this specific use case).

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

productlinks = []
sam=[]
for x in range(1,3):
    url=f'https://www.aacr.org/page/{x}/?s=breast+cancer&search_type=global'
    r=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
    productlist=soup.find_all('div',class_='blog-content')
    for item in productlist:
        title=soup.find_all('h3')
        for single in title:
            print(single.a['title'])
```

result:

```
Breast Cancer
Male Breast Cancer
Breast Cancer Prevention (PDQ®)
Breast Cancer Screening (PDQ®)
Breast Cancer Treatment During Pregnancy (PDQ®)
Breast Cancer Treatment (PDQ®)
Male Breast Cancer Treatment (PDQ®)
Carcinoma of Unknown Primary
Overcoming Triple-Negative Breast Cancer
Living with Metastatic Breast Cancer
Surviving Metastatic Breast Cancer; Advocating for Other Cancer Patients
Living With Stage 4 Breast Cancer
Choosing to Enjoy Life Despite Metastatic Breast Cancer
A Breast and Colon Cancer Survivor Supports Cancer Research
Pedaling for Cancer Research
Emily Garnett
Supporting Increased Funding for Clinical Trials
Raising Awareness of Male Breast Cancer
Keeping Breast Cancer at Bay with Immunotherapy
Recovering after Breast Cancer Treatment Thanks to Prehab and Rehab
Takae Brewer, MD
Thankful for Clinical Trials
Bianca Lundien Kennedy
Gina Favors
Running to Beat Leukemia (and All Cancers)
Patricia Fox
Survivor Profile: An Unlikely Pivot
Program
Advances in Breast Cancer Research
Program
Breast Cancer
Male Breast Cancer
Breast Cancer Prevention (PDQ®)
Breast Cancer Screening (PDQ®)
Breast Cancer Treatment During Pregnancy (PDQ®)
Breast Cancer Treatment (PDQ®)
Male Breast Cancer Treatment (PDQ®)
Carcinoma of Unknown Primary
Overcoming Triple-Negative Breast Cancer
Living with Metastatic Breast Cancer
Surviving Metastatic Breast Cancer; Advocating for Other Cancer Patients
Living With Stage 4 Breast Cancer
Choosing to Enjoy Life Despite Metastatic Breast Cancer
A Breast and Colon Cancer Survivor Supports Cancer Research
Pedaling for Cancer Research
Emily Garnett
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the `title` attribute, just change the last `for loop` to this:

```
for item in productlist:
    a_tag =item.find('a')
    print(a_tag['title'])
```

Output:

```
Breast Cancer
Male Breast Cancer
Breast Cancer Prevention (PDQ®)
Breast Cancer Screening (PDQ®)
Breast Cancer Treatment During Pregnancy (PDQ®)
Breast Cancer Treatment (PDQ®)
Male Breast Cancer Treatment (PDQ®)
Carcinoma of Unknown Primary
Overcoming Triple-Negative Breast Cancer
Living with Metastatic Breast Cancer
Surviving Metastatic Breast Cancer; Advocating for Other Cancer Patients
Living With Stage 4 Breast Cancer
Choosing to Enjoy Life Despite Metastatic Breast Cancer
A Breast and Colon Cancer Survivor Supports Cancer Research
Pedaling for Cancer Research
Emily Garnett
Supporting Increased Funding for Clinical Trials
Raising Awareness of Male Breast Cancer
Keeping Breast Cancer at Bay with Immunotherapy
Recovering after Breast Cancer Treatment Thanks to Prehab and Rehab
Takae Brewer, MD
Thankful for Clinical Trials
Bianca Lundien Kennedy
Gina Favors
Running to Beat Leukemia (and All Cancers)
Patricia Fox
Survivor Profile: An Unlikely Pivot
Program
Advances in Breast Cancer Research
Program
```